# How to get a simplified circuit out of three smaller circuits?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I completed the three basic tasks in three independent circuits; however, the optional part is a bit confusing for me; how could I simplify them in one single circuit? Should I find inspiration in the truth tables or in the logical formulas of the 3 circuits?

I tried using boolean algebra manipulation to split them in a general circuit, but failed. How could I approach this? I need to implement it in a diagram, posteriorly build it on a breadboard and I can only use OR AND NOT gates.

Comment: I'm not sur to understand f3, what is the meaning of whenever an odd number of the inputs is high ? you mean the combination of the tree inputs a,b and c : 001, 011,..111 ?

Comment: If you construct the truth table for all the functions, it will become clear. You can use f1 and f2 and combine them to produce f3 directly (No need to implement one of the functions separately this way).

Comment: @codo an odd number of inputs, only any one high or all three high,  `001`,`010`,`100`,`111`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your description exactly one output will be `true` at any time, so pick the two simplest circuits and combine their outputs to get the third output.

You want the third output `true` when the other two are `false`

Given that you solved the other individual outputs you should be able to take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

If F1 is low AND F2 is low then at least one input is high but not 2 - this gives you the means of producing F3.